# How to make a NodeJs function wait?

Tags: javascript, node.js, timeout, wait

For example I have these two functions:

```
var count= function(){
    for(i=1;i<=3;i++){
        console.log(i);
    }
    setTimeout(function(){
        for(i=1;i<=3;i++){
            console.log(-i);
         }
    },2000);
} 

var letters = function(){
     var charSet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvvwxyz'
     for(i=0;i<3;i++){
         console.log(charSet[i]);
     }
}
```

When I execute them in this order:

```
count();
letters();
```

I expect to get as output:

```
1 2 3 -1 -2 -3 a b c
```

But what I get is:

```
1 2 3 a b c -1 -2 -3
```

Why the function does not wait the Timeout to finish? How can I achieve the desired behaviour?

Comment: NodeJS is asynchronous by nature. However I can't test it at the moment. Check out https://www.npmjs.com/package/sleep and see if that works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason that you aren't getting `1 2 3 -1 -2 -3 a b c` is because your code does not stop at the `setTimeout(...)` call. This is because many JavaScript methods, by nature, are [asynchronous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asynchrony_(computer_programming)). This means that they will not stop the flow of your code. That means when you call `setTimeout(...)`, the JavaScript interpreter will make sure that the function passed into `setTimeout` is run in `2000`ms, but does not stop and wait for it. It will continue on its normal execution flow, onto the next instruction.

If you wanted it to wait, you could put the `letters()` call after you print out the remaining numbers (`-1, -2, -3`).

```
    setTimeout(function(){
        for(i=1;i<=3;i++){
            console.log(-i);
         }
         letters();
    },2000);
```

Answer (score 2):

> Why the function does not wait the Timeout to finish?

Because that's not how [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout) works.

What actually happens is you put in a request to have your function run in no less than X milliseconds (2000 in your case). The JS runtime will wait for all other code to finish running then see if it's been at least X milliseconds. Once it has, your function will run. But in the meantime, you can run any other JS code. It intentionally doesn't block other code from running.

> How can I achieve the desired behaviour?

The best answer is structure your code differently. You need to learn to work with asynchronous events. The simplest way would be to use a callback function:

```js
var count = function(cb) {
  for (i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
    console.log(i);
  }
  setTimeout(function() {
    for (i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
      console.log(-i);
    }
    
    // Run the function we passed to it after the rest is done
    cb();
  }, 2000);
}

var letters = function() {
  var charSet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvvwxyz'
  for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    console.log(charSet[i]);
  }
}

count(letters); // Pass `letters` as a callback so it will be called after `count` is done
```

Answer (score 1):

Because `setTimeout` schedules the second loop to run later (in ~2 seconds), then returns immediately.

Node.js is for asynchronous, event-driven programming. You do not want to be blocking execution at all - the behaviour you are asking for is not "desired" at all.

I suggest you read up about Node.js and asynchronous programming, then re-visit what it is you are actually trying to do. You probably want something more like this:

```
function count(callback) {
    for (i=1; i<=3; i++){
        console.log(i);
    }
    setTimeout(function() {
        for(i=1;i<=3;i++){
            console.log(-i);
        }
        callback();
    }, 2000);
} 

function letters() {
     var charSet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvvwxyz'
     for (i=0; i<3; i++){
         console.log(charSet[i]);
     }
}
```

And run it like:

```
count(letters);
```